# Creating h1 tags for bilingual email

Tags: header, tags, accessibility

I need to create bilingual emails going out to clients, which will have the English content followed by the French below. The French is translated from the English so they both have titles set to h1. But when I test the accessibility it says there are two h1 headings.

How can I fix that so that it only has one h1 heading? Would I have to create if or class? How would the css look like?

Thank you.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem at all to have two H1. It's much better than only one H1, because it allows to go directly to the french version.